# Template deduction for template aliasing with default value

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, c++20, ctad

According to [P1814R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html), the template deduction should work for alias with default value. With GCC 12.2(-std=c++20), the following code built successfully. However, in MSVC v19.33(/std:c++20) (which supports P1814R0), I got an error

```
<source>(10): error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'Matrix3'
```

Is this a MSVC bug or I missed some configurations in MSVC?

Test codes:

```
template <typename Type, int Row, int Col, int Options = 0>
class Matrix {
    Type storage[Row * Col];
};

template <typename Type = double>
using Matrix3 = Matrix<Type, 3, 3>;

int main() {
    Matrix3 a;
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nbfaxY7vs

Comment: Yeah, even directly specifying the msvc standard doesn't help: https://godbolt.org/z/hMxK1M9x1

Comment: It seems that `Matrix3<>` [works for MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/3Khc7zY6a).

Comment: You need `Matrix3 a{};` for MSVC. (Not sure if the `{}` here is necessary for the current wording)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for saying: I don't want to provide template arguments, just use the defaults, should be:

```
Matrix3<> a;
```

Indeed C++20 adopted [P1814](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1814r0.html) into section [over.match.class.deduct](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.class.deduct#3), so it seems that the following should be valid since C++20:

```
Matrix3 a;
```

---

### GCC

As the OP mentions in a comment [GCC rejected the above in C++17 and accepts it in C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/KeYox9ePM).

---

### MSVC

As mention by @康桓瑋 [MSVC accepts since C++20 only the form](https://godbolt.org/z/heW1r4TjM):

```
Matrix3 a{};
```

but still rejects:

```
Matrix3 a;
```

---

### Clang

[Clang still rejects both](https://godbolt.org/z/4YadbqjT6).

---

### To Summarize

It seems that GCC is updated for C++20 on that respect, MSVC did part of the way and Clang is lagging behind.

Comment: By adding <> the compiler is forced to use default template argument. I think there is no CTAD here anymore. I changed gcc standard to -std=c++17, and actually gcc gave me an error ```error: alias template deduction only available with '-std=c++20' or '-std=gnu++20'```. Since clang does not implement P1814R0, the clang output seems reasonable to me. However, MSVC claims to implement P1814R0, but I got some unexpected error.